# How can I remove duplicates from two different lists, one containing only int and the other one containing mixed int and str?

Tags: python, list

I have a df with some columns. The entries in the list shall be filtered/have their duplicates removed based on two of the columns: one of the columns contains only numbers, while the other column contains mixed strings (Letters + a number) and numbers.

What I am trying to do is: Compare the numbers from the first column with:

1. the numbers from the end of each string in the second column (last X characters always)
2. the numbers from the second column
   and then remove the duplicated entries.

Entries either have information in one of those columns, otherwise there is an empty string.

Example:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3

ABC.  | 12345 | ""

DEF.  | ""    | DEF12345

GHI.  | ""    | 12345
```

As you can see, we have 3 different entries. I want to filter based on column 2 and 3.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the expected output?

Comment: Tried extracting the last X characters from column 3 into a new column and then converting them to int, however since Col 3 has mixed entries (str and int) I get NaN for the ints.

Expected output would be the same table without the duplicates. In this case, only the first entry would be in the output, since all 3 are duplicates based on the criteria.

Comment: For your example what would be the result?  Would it be just one row with DEF 12345 DEF12345 or something else?

Comment: Also, is it only 'DEF' that you will find or other chars as well? What about the empty strings? How shall "" be converted? Please add more details to your question, add a comprehensive set of inputs and the desired output.

Comment: It is not important if the output is the first, second or third entry, since they contain duplicated information. As an output I'd expect only one of them, unchanged from the input dataframe, e.g. ABC. | 12345 | "'. The characters are mixed, I would need to extract the last 9 characters from a string that is up to 25 characters long. Those last 9 characters will always be a number, and it is possible that this number is already entered into either column 2 or as a sole number in column 3.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Your comments are misleading, the last 9 chars of 'DEF12345' include string characters. Please include proper examples, otherwise, it is just a waste of time. Please, read this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @alec_djinn I'm sorry, my thought was that if I could understand how to make it work for the current example, I would be able to transform it for my data. Thank you for your answer below. A real example would contain similar entries in column C: DEF12312300000123000012345. This is why I stated that the last 9 characters of the entry will always be a number with no string characters.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov I hope my example helps. You can try using `return int(val[-9:])` and see if it really fits your dataset. The overall concept stays the same, 1) make a function to parse your entries and return the desired integer 2) apply it to the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your DataFrame is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Col 1':['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'],
        'Col 2':[12345, '', ''],
        'Col 3':['','DEF12345', 12345]
    }
)

print(df)

  Col 1  Col 2     Col 3
0   ABC  12345          
1   DEF         DEF12345
2   GHI            12345
```

You have to build a custom function to properly parse and convert the values and then [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) it to the columns you want.

Given the lack of clarity of your question, here I can make just a dummy example, you will have to modify it to make it work for your real-case scenario.

```
def str_to_int(val):
    if type(val) is int:
        return val
    elif type(val) is str:
        if val == '':
            return 0 #you have to choose how to deal with this
        else:
            return int(val[3:]) #assuming you have always 3 letters before the number

df['Col 2'] = df['Col 2'].apply(str_to_int)
df['Col 3'] = df['Col 3'].apply(str_to_int)

print(df)

  Col 1  Col 2  Col 3
0   ABC  12345      0
1   DEF      0  12345
2   GHI      0  12345
```

Now you can easily find duplicates since all the entries are numbers.

```
#Make a new column that keeps only the non 0 integers
def exclude_zeros(row):
    return row['Col 2'] or row['Col 3']

df['Col 4'] = df.apply(exclude_zeros, axis=1)

#Remove the duplicates and keep only the relevant data
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Col 4', keep='first')[['Col 1', 'Col 4']]

print(df)

Col 1  Col 4
0   ABC  12345
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My next question would be: Assuming that I create 2 different columns where I have successfully removed the unneeded information and have, say "999999" instead of the 0s that replace all empty strings. Is there a way to filter for duplicates in these 2 new columns while ignoring all "999999" entries? pd.drop_duplicates doesn't seem to have such a parameter in itself. Thanks again!

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov I still having problems understanding what is the output you are looking for. Do you want to remove rows or columns based on the duplicates? Can you please make a clear example of it? If you can't post an example of input and desired output, I can't help.

Comment: I want to remove rows based on duplicating entries in the two columns. Based on your last table that you posted on your answer, I would like to remove "DEF" and "GHI" rows, since both of them have the same number as "ABC" entry.

Input will be just like the first table in your answer above. Output should be only the first entry "ABC" without any changes in its columns. That is why I will create two separate columns while applying the defined function above. My question is: Given that we have Col 2 and Col 3, how can I remove duplicates while ignoring all "0" entries?

Comment: If I don't ignore all the "0" entries in Col 2 and Col 3, all rows will be deleted since 0 is a duplicate now, I would like to avoid that. Thank you for your time and excuse my poor way of describing it, sadly I don't know how and if I can post formated tables just like above in the original post!

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Check it now. I think it is what you want. Again, without a proper input example, it is hard to foresee the edge cases, you will have to adjust the code to your specific dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems to be working on my test set, will try it out on my real data now.